# Get Index of a LongListSelector SelectedItem with JumpList and DataSource as List<AlphaKeyGroup<Artist>> where Artist is a custom class

Tags: c#, indexof, longlistselector

I have the below class `ArtistAlbum`:

```
    public class Artist
{
    public string ArtistName { get; set; }
}
```

This `LonglistSelector` belongs to the `MusicPage.xaml` and after getting the Index of the `LongListSelector.SelectedItem`, I would like to retrieve the details of the `Artist` Collection at the above retrieved Index at a different page and hence the use of `GlobalVars`. But, I'm not able to get the Index of the `LongListSelector`.

```
private void llsArtists_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Getting the index here from llsArtists.ItemsSource by using IndexOf
    // doesn't work and returns -1
    // Get the ID here and save it to GlobalVars._artistID;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ArtistDetail.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

The below method is responsible for getting the results into the collection.

```
void GetArtists()
    {

        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < ml.Artists.Count; i++)
            {
                sourceArtists.Add(new Artist
                {
                    ArtistName = ml.Artists[i].Name.ToUpper(),
                });


                List<AlphaKeyGroup<Artist>> DataSource = AlphaKeyGroup<Artist>.CreateGroups(sourceArtists,
                      System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture,
                      (Artist s) => { return s.ArtistName; }, true);

                    llsArtists.ItemsSource = DataSource;

            }


        });
    }
```

Please see the image below for the ItemSource structure
[image: Nested List]

Comment: Did you try my answer from your previous question, only with a cast to `Artist` instead?

Comment: Hi Yuval, 
Yes, I did - it still returns a -1 index and the type is a `Artist` which it should be.

Comment: It should also be noted that the ItemsSource is a `AlphaKeyGroup` (used by the JumpList) and therefore it also contains group headers for the empty JumpList. Also, apologies if this may not be the best way to put it, but it also like a nested List (please see my image in the question). So I suspect, I might have to use 1IndexOf(something.IndexOf(x))` ?? Maybe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has solved my query:

As my ItemsSource was originally `Artist` but it was then converted to `List<AlphaKeyGroup<Artist>>`, I then selected my `List<AlphaKeyGroup<Artist>>` as the ItemsSource to get the `.IndexOf` by using the following:

1. I first got the `Model.Name` attribute of the e.AddedItems by using this void

   ```
    private void llsArtists_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       // Getting the index here from llsArtists.ItemsSource by using IndexOf
       // doesn't work and returns -1
       // Get the ID here and save it to GlobalVars._artistID;
       var artist = (Artist)e.AddedItems[0];
       GetSelectedArtist(artist.ArtistName);
       //int selectedIndex = llsArtists.ItemsSource.IndexOf(llsArtists.SelectedItem as AlphaKeyGroup<Artist>);
       NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ArtistDetail.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
   }
   ```
2. and then using LINQ, I iterated to get my SelectedItemIndex

But I believe it could also be retrieved by a simple .IndexOf replacing the ItemsSource as the AlphaKeyGroup source. (Haven't checked this yet)

```
public Artist GetSelectedArtist(string aName)
        {
            var result = (sourceArtists.Single(u => u.ArtistName == aName));
            var index = sourceArtists.IndexOf(result);
            GlobalVars._artistID = index;
            return result;
        }
```